# isschildwroteandexecuted marked as critical security issue

Tags: iis, w3wp

We are facing sudden security issue stated with below details

1. isschildwroteandexecuted
2. an iis sub-process wrote a new executable and a sub-process ran it

And reported with below additional details as
exploit public-facing application gain issue

I am blank with this issue details. Can anyone help me regarding this issue details.

Thanks in advance.

We have tried to access IP tied up with request and everything seems valid provider.

We need to find and block IP which trying to exploit.

Comment: You didn't give enough details. If a security scan reveals some vulnerabilities of your web server, show us the exact scan report, not some random texts you typed on your own. No one can guess what happened from scattered pieces.

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your problem clearly. please post more details information about your issue.